# How can I make my bootstrapped install as simple as possible?

Tags: installation, bootstrapper

I'm using WiX to create an installer and generate a bootstrapper. The bootstrapper comes out as a separate file that does its thing and then executes my MSI installer. I want to make this process as simple as possible. I don't want the user to have to unzip files or anything, I'd like to them to just be able to download and double click a single file.

Can this be done? If so, how? If not, how simple can I make it?

OneClick is not an option, as my app is service based.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-afer-extraction-from-7zip-sfx-archive) on superuser.com. This [guide](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/39048-how-to-make-a-7-zip-switchless-installer/) looks very clear. Basically you will use [7zS.sfx](http://docs.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/sfx.htm) to create a self extracting archive which will automatically be extracted, your setup.exe will be run, and all files removed afterwards.